# Can't constraint to association table on Laravel and MySql

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

I'm using MYSQL v5.7 and Laravel v5.6, I've added foreign key on product table.

But getting error like this.

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `product` add constraint `product_category_id_foreign` foreign key (`category_id`) references `category` (`id`) on delete cascade)
```

This is my product table

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('product', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->integer('admin_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->integer('price');
            $table->binary('image')->nullable(false)->change();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
        Schema::table('product', function($table){
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('category')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('admin_id')->references('id')->on('admin')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

This is my category table

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('category', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: Try to add `$table->engine = "InnoDB";` at the beginning of your schema.

Comment: not can,, but when i am delete category_id foreign key from product table,, the migrate succes and just admin_id is migration.. why ? you know ?

Comment: I would say try to delete all your your tables an remigrate again

Answer (score 0):

One possible problem is a difference in datatype between `product.category_id` (the foreign key column) and `category.id` (the referenced primary key).

(This is just one possibility. The problem might be due to something else.)

But we should first check that the datatypes of the two columns match *exactly*. If they don't match, then we won't be able to define an InnoDB foreign key constraint.

My guess is that `category.id` is defined as `BIGINT` datatype.

(That's a guess, I'm not an expert on Laravel schema builder, but I do see that schema builder does a grand job of masking/hiding the actual SQL definition of the MySQL table.)

(It's not at all clear why Laravel requires the datatype for the foreign key column to be specified. We know it has match the datatype of the referenced column.)

---

My guess at a fix is to change this line

from:

```
 $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
```

to:

```
 $table->bigInteger('category_id')->nullable();
```

Comment: not can,, but when i am delete category_id foreign key from product table,, the migrate succes and just admin_id is migration.. why ? you know ?